# Minimum AWS policy actions required for retrieving Glacier files through S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to create a policy for an IAM account that will allow an employee to have full read permissions for our S3 (lifecycled to Glacier) buckets, with **no** unnecessary write abilities as to avoid any kind of damage to our backups.

This version of read needs to include the ability to initiate a file restore (Glacier) and download it.

I've created a policy that allows the full **List** and **Read** access level groups, but I get an Access Denied error when I try to initiate a file restore through S3 Browser.

I tried a mixture of trial and error, and guessing at which actions sounded relevant, but had no luck.

What are the minimum actions I should be selecting from the **Write**/**Permission management**/**Tagging groups** to ensure that Glacier files can be retrieved, with no unnecessary write access?

Thanks

Comment: How about `s3:RestoreObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct option to select was **s3:RestoreObject**

Credit: Michael - sqlbot Dec 8 '17 at 13:08